# How to get instance root volume id in CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to get instance root volume id in CloudFormation template? Instance was created from AMI image. I want to specify volume id for Cloudwatch Alarm. Fn::GetAtt function can't return it, after reading documentation a lot i found only one way to do it: "custom resource", but it's too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating the volume first (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html) and then attaching it to `/dev/sda1` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volumeattachment.html).

Although the doc doesn't rule this out, I'm not completely confident it will work. I assume you will at least need the right snapshot ID from the desired AMI.

If it happens to work, the example under the second link shows how to then reference and get the volume id. **And to suggest an alternative, I do believe instance metrics provide aggregate IO for ephemeral disks** (see EC2 under http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ec2-metricscollected.html).

I realize you're not asking for ideas in reengineering your stack... but depending on what this disk IO actually represents, you might realize additional benefits by switching to instance store (free and very fast) or additional EBS (many down-the-road benefits when e.g. mounted for data directories for databases). Both of these would also solve your immediate problem.

Comment: Well, it is working in a wrong way when you update instance. If instance update requires instance replacing, it says, that volume is already attached to an instance (old one), both for VolumeAttachment and "Volumes" instance property. "BlockDeviceMappings" works fine, but I can't get volume Id.

Aggregate metrics simply don't have required metric (volume idle time), at least in AWS web interface.

Comment: @gray, I see. If offloading this io to secondary volumes isn't otherwise appropriate, I don't think `DependsOn` will be much help with that (I've heard of that exact paradox). I would carefully weigh secondary volumes against creating infrastructure for custom resources, and I won't lie, it would be a nobrainer for me.

Comment: Yes, it would be paradox, as VolumeAttachment documentation reads "Attaches an Amazon EBS volume to a _running_ instance". I don't understand point about secondary volumes, actually my instance already have 2 volumes, they both EBS, and I need monitoring for both of them. I asked a question about root volume as I thought, that this is widespread situation and I will get answer to question faster.

Comment: @gray What's the desired behavior for you, change AMI (for example) but keep same volumes / data? Or change AMI and have all associated stuff get reprovisioned from scratch?

Comment: The second one. I have creation policy for instance and I need old instance and new running before signal is sent.